# `mat-table` element is generating an error about `dataSource` being an unknown attribute of table

Tags: javascript, angular, material-ui

I am learning material library for Angular. I am using Angular version 15.0.1 and material version 15.0.1.
I am trying to add a mat-table to my form (`schedule.allocator.component.html`):

[image]

... but getting the error:
`Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.ngtsc(-998002) schedule.allocator.component.ts(13, 8): Error occurs in the template of component ScheduleAllocatorComponent.`

Part of my `schedule.allocator.component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TimeHandler } from 'src/app/_helpers/time.handler';
import { Account, Role } from 'src/app/_models';
import { Schedule } from 'src/app/_models/schedule';
import { SchedulePoolElement } from 'src/app/_models/schedulepoolelement';
import { UserFunction } from 'src/app/_models/userfunction';
import { AccountService, AlertService } from 'src/app/_services';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import {MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';


const dateFormat = `${environment.dateFormat}`;
@Component({ 
  templateUrl: './schedule.allocator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule.allocator.component.less']
})


export class ScheduleAllocatorComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  @Output() onScheduledAdded: EventEmitter<any>;
  id: string;

  dataSource : any;
...
```

I am importing `MatTableModule` in my app.module.ts class.

Can some expert in this area help me to solve the issue.

Comment: you should include in the module "where you declare your component": MatSortModule, MatTableModule and MatPaginatorModule

Comment: I did include all three modules to my component import list - didn't help. Is that what you meant?

Comment: no you have to import them in your app.module.ts

Comment: @JanuszDalecki, the "Modules" are imported in app.module (or in another module), in Components you only import "Components"

Comment: OK. I did - same problem

Comment: I also imported in my component `MatTableDataSource` but it did not help.

Comment: Sometime vs code don't update, did you try close vs code and re-open ? delete node_modules and npm install ?

Comment: You are right. I have deleted node_modules and install them again. It works. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: How do I mark your help as the solution?

Comment: Sorry for the too early glory. Now when I build it give me an error `'mat-table' is not a known element:`

Comment: Did you also imported : import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table'; in the app.module.ts ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign dataSource:

```
datasource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't belive it. I have moved :
MaterialModule,
MatSortModule,
MatTableModule,
MatPaginatorModule

from app.module.ts to the module that contains the declaration for my component - and now it compiles and builds.

Thank you for the help you have given to me.

Comment: i'm glad it worked ! But you shouldn't do that, it's not a good practice, you should instead leave them in your app.module.ts. Maybe the error is in the app.module.ts where you put them in the wroong section (declaration, import, export) or maybe in the architecture of your app. I can maybe help you about that if you post the module. Please note also that this stackblitz from the material documentation can help you with the imports: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I have created stackblits of my app here. Do you mind to check if I have done this time the proper fix please? Nothing against architecture at least. The component is schedule.allocator.component.ts/html

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i got it. First you needed to delete node_modules and npm install.
But for your real problem, i think you have misunderstood the architecture of the modules of you app.

If you want to regroup severals components for whatever reason you can create a module file. Then you import the component inside along with every lib that they are using. Then this module is exported to app.module.ts. This is used to seperate imports of library. But if you want to use something globally (in your app.module) you have to export them.

We thought it would be enough to put mat-table declarations in app.module.ts but you didn't say your component had a module on it's own. That's why it didn't work. for it to work you have to do : the components module import app.module and app.module export material components